# When making a compiler, what's the best way for compiling to machine code in the backend?

Tags: compiler, assembly, backend

I know that a lot of compilers use an assembler to compile to machine code, to make an executable (compiled program).

Some people even made their own assemblers, or they just use an existing assembler, or they just transcompile to C, or they just use some other VM like JVM, or LLVM.

What's the fastest and easiest way to compile to machine code? Using LLVM? Making your own assembler? What's the most efficient way to quickly make a backend?

Comment: "What's the fastest and easiest way to compile to machine code?"  What is the  representation you're starting with?  Source code? Assembly text?  Intermediate data structure?  "best way for compiling to machine code in the backend?" -- from what?

Comment: Source code.
I've showed examples: LLVM, JVM, transcompiling to C, assembly, etc, just to get it to an executable.

Comment: So, you're asking if writing your own assembler will be faster than using LLVM to go from C source code to machine code?

Comment: I'm asking, what's the fastest way to make the backend? Like fastest development time. Would it be faster to compile to assembly, make your own assembler, or compiling to LLVM, or transcompiling to C, etc.

Comment: It depends on what sort of language you’re compiling, and to a lesser degree what your target architecture requirements are. You’re going to have to be more specific.

Comment: Why is making your own assembler an option of consideration?

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what you want to do.  If this is for learning how a computer works, you may want to learn assembler for your machine, that is write small programs in machine code and learn how they work, and how a good debugger can help you.  When you understand that, you also better understand how much work a compiler actually does, and is better suited for learning more.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest development time very often translates to "use what you're familiar with" (if that is usable for the purpose at all). If you're not already familiar with compiler backends (preferably multiple, to be able to make an informed choice) then a significant part of your development time will be spent on learning the framework.

That said, for a "toy" project or something that is going to be used by few people in a known context, for example some DSL, I'd compile to a "high" level language that you know well which integrates well with the rest of your project. If your goal is to create stand-alone executables, my suggestion would be to use C as C compilers are ubiquitous.

For serious programming language development, I would suggest to learn LLVM if you want to do static compilation. It does seem to have some weak spots for just-in-time compilation, so if you want to do that you may have to look around a bit more. Caveat: I've never learnt LLVM myself, so take this with a grain of salt.

But you probably should not try serious programming language development if you're not already able to answer this question on your own :-)

Comment: I should have been more specific. I would of just used GAS or NASM for assembly, but it wouldn't be cross-platform code, so I'd have to make assembly for each OS separately which seems painful. So I found C another option because it would be way more portable than assembly. So, the point is I'm trying to make a cross-platform compiler.

Comment: Then it looks like C would be a reasonable start, with LLVM as a future option when you feel you're too limited by C.